# How to make a report command in Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am attempting to make a report command for my bot, but I seem to get no response whatsoever

```
bot.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');

    switch(args[0]){

        case 'report':
            message.delete(3000);
            let target = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
            if(!target) return message.channel.send('Please provide a user that you wish to report').then(m => m.delete(15000));
            
            let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
            if(!reason) return message.channel.send(`Please provide a reason for reporting **${target.user.username}**`).then(m => m.delete(15000));
 
            let reportChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name === "▸logs");
            
            message.channel.send('Your report has been filed to the staff team. Thank you for reporting!').then(m => m.delete(15000));
            reportChannel.send(`**${message.author.username}** has reported **${target.user.username}** for **${reason}**.`);
        break;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using discord.js v12, I've made some edits to make this code works.
First, the new discord.js Message#delete() method requires now a parameter:

So change:

• `message.delete(3000);` -> `message.delete({timeout: 3000});`

• `message.guild.members.get()` -> `message.guild.members.cache.get()`

• Also, it's `args.slice(2)` instead of `args.slice(1)` to properly remove the user mention too.

Here is the final result ^

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');
  switch(args[0]){
      case 'report':
          message.delete({timeout: 3000});
          let target = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
          if(!target) return message.channel.send('Please provide a user that you wish to report').then(m => m.delete({timeout: 15000}));

          let reason = args.slice(2).join(" ");
          if(!reason) return message.channel.send(`Please provide a reason for reporting **${target.user.username}**`).then(m => m.delete({timeout: 15000}));

          let reportChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name === "▸logs");

          message.channel.send('Your report has been filed to the staff team. Thank you for reporting!').then(m => m.delete({timeout: 15000}));
          reportChannel.send(`**${message.author.username}** has reported **${target.user.username}** for **${reason}**.`);
      break;
    };
});
```

Comment: After trying this out I got the errors (if no target was provided and if no reason was provided), but when I try to provide a reason it doesn't send the confirmation message nor the message to the chosen channel, I also attempted switching the reportChannel to
`message.guild.channels.cache.get('[channel id]')`
and it still did not work

Comment: Hum strange, I just tried it and it perfectly works for me

Comment: I got it to work by adding this line: 
`if(args[1] === target, args[2] === reason){ [confirmation message code and reportChannel code here] }`

Comment: Oh okay perfect :)